# How do you create new templates using SPE?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have created sitecore template using powershell extension. Here is my powershell script:

```
$template = New-Item  -Path "/sitecore/templates/PowershellTask" -Name "testtemplate" -type "{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}"

$standardvalues = New-Item -Parent $item -Name "__Standard Values" -type $template.ID
$template.Editing.BeginEdit()
$template["__Standard values"] = $standardvalues.ID
$template.Editing.EndEdit()
```

I don't know how to add fields to this template. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote this a while back. The script includes a helper function for creating new templates. Feel free to modify this to include adding Standard Values.

```powershell
function New-TemplateItem {
    param(    
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]    
        [string]$Path,    
        [string]$Icon,   
        [string]$BaseTemplate,    
        [PSCustomObject[]]$Fields    
    )

    $itemTemplate = New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template"    
    $itemTemplate."__Base Template" = "{1930BBEB-7805-471A-A3BE-4858AC7CF696}"

    if($BaseTemplate) {    
        $itemTemplate."__Base Template" = $BaseTemplate    
    }

    if($Icon) {    
        $itemTemplate."__Icon" = $Icon    
    }   
        
    if($Fields) {    
        foreach($field in $fields) {    
            $sectionPath = "$($Path)/Data"    
            if($field.Section) {    
                $sectionPath = "$($Path)/$($field.Section)"    
            }

            if(-not(Test-Path -Path $sectionPath)) {    
                New-Item -Path $sectionPath -ItemType "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template section" | Out-Null    
            }

            $fieldItem = New-Item -Path "$($sectionPath)/$($field.Name)" -ItemType "/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template field"    
            $fieldItem.BeginEdit() | Out-Null    
            $fieldItem["Type"] = $field.Type    
            $fieldItem["Title"] = $field.Title    
            $fieldItem["Source"] = $field.Source    
            $fieldItem.EndEdit() | Out-Null    
        }    
    }    
}    

$fields = @(    
    [PSCustomObject]@{    
        "Name" = "Artist"    
        "Title" = "Artist Title"    
        "Type" = "Single-Line Text"    
        "Section" = "Details"    
    },    
    [PSCustomObject]@{    
        "Name" = "Description"    
        "Title" = "Artist Description"    
        "Type" = "Rich Text"    
        "Section" = "Details"    
        "Source" = "/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default"    
    }    
)    

$templatePath = "master:/sitecore/templates/User Defined/SetList"    
$baseTemplateIds = "{1930BBEB-7805-471A-A3BE-4858AC7CF696}"    
Remove-Item -Path $templatePath -Recurse    
New-TemplateItem -Path $templatePath -Icon "office/32x32/earth_music.png" -BaseTemplate $baseTemplateIds -Fields $fields
```

Comment: Can u help me out with assigning **source** value to droplink field in sitecore template.  
    ` DropLink{
           $spiltedValue=$importData.DropLink -split ",";
            if(!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($spiltedValue))){
              foreach ( $fieldName in $spiltedValue ) {
                $field=New-Item -Parent $sectionValue -Name $fieldName -type "{455A3E98-A627-4B40-8035-E683A0331AC7}"
                $field.Type="DropLink"
                $field.**??**="/sitecore/content/ListManagerTask"
              }
            }
           break
        }`Don't know how to give path?

Comment: Perhaps this article explains what possible values can go in the source field. http://sitecore.wonderamy.com/2011/03/using-source-property.html